# Android Studio (Firebase) : Gradle is not getting sync

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am new to Google firebase. I followed all steps as given on link https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

My Android Studio version: 2.1.1

I simply added dependencies as per instructions

I unable sync the gradle. Following error is showing. Please help and thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your `build.gradle` top level and module level files

Answer (score 2):

In the **SDK Manager** -> **SDK Tools** tab install **Google Play Services** (rev 30) and **Google Repository** (rev 26). When done sync and Build your project.